# Dataframe to datatable r.net fastly

Tags: c#, datatable, r.net

I would like to know if there is a better method to convert a datanet from rnet to a datatable of system.data or something like that.
Currently, what I'm doing is

```
Dataframe dataset = engine.evaluate ("some dataframe"). AsDataframe ();
DataTable dtable = new DataTable ();

  For (int i = 0; i <dataset.ColumnCount; ++ i)
             {
                 Dtable.Columns.Add (dataset.ColumnNames [i]);
             }

             For (int k = 0; k <dataset.RowCount; ++ k)
             {
                 Dtable.Rows.Add (dataset.GetRow (k) .DataFrame);

             }

             For (int i = 0; i <dataset.RowCount; i ++)
             {
                 For (int j = 0; j <dataset.ColumnCount; j ++)
                 {
                     Dtable.Rows [i] [j] = dataset [i, j];
                 }
             }
```

However, the method is very slow and wanted to know if there is another method faster.

regards

Answer (score 0):

You can easily eliminate one for loop

```
Dataframe dataset = engine.evaluate ("some dataframe"). AsDataframe ();
DataTable dtable = new DataTable ();

For (int i = 0; i <dataset.ColumnCount; ++ i)
{
   Dtable.Columns.Add (dataset.ColumnNames [i]);
}


For (int i = 0; i <dataset.RowCount; i ++)
{
   DataRow newRow = Dtable.Rows.Add();
   For (int j = 0; j <dataset.ColumnCount; j ++)
   {
      newRow[j] = dataset [i, j];
   }
}
```